# spring boot websocket handshake takes too long

Tags: nginx, websocket, wireshark, spring-websocket, tcpdump

I am using websocket spring boot to establish websocket. But it takes too long to handshake the websocket. Could you please help to point me out?

[image]

websocket connect quickly, but it takes more than 6 minutes